# Carousel back button is not working, why?

Tags: jquery

The code shown below is for a picture carousel. The right arrow works perfectly fine. So I tried to simply do the opposite for the left one, but apparently that is not correct. Is there something simple that I have done wrong, or is this simply not a way you can do this? When I click it, nothing at all happens. The dot doesn't move, nor the picture. But the right arrow, works perfectly, even wrapping back around when it reaches the end. I appreciate and and all help.

```
var main = function(){
"use strict";

$('.right-arrow').click(function(){
    var currentSlide = $('.active-slide');
    var nextSlide = currentSlide.next();

    var currentDot = $('.active-dot');
    var nextDot = currentDot.next();

    if(currentSlide.is(':last-child')){
        nextSlide = $('.slide').first();
        nextDot = $('.dot').first();

    }

    currentSlide.fadeOut(600, function(){

        nextSlide.fadeIn(600).addClass('active-slide');

    }).removeClass('active-slide');

    currentDot.removeClass('active-dot');
    nextDot.addClass('active-dot');


});

$('.left-arrow').click(function(){
        var currentSlide = ('.active-slide');
        var prevSlide = currentSlide.prev();    

        var currentDot = $('.active-dot');
        var prevDot = currentDot.prev();

        if(prevSlide.is(':first-child')){
            prevSlide = $('.slide').last();
            prevDot = $('.dot').last(); 
        }

        currentSlide.fadeOut(600, function(){
            prevSlide.fadeIn(600).addClass('active-slide'); 
        }).removeClass('active-slide');

        currentDot.removeClass('active-dot');
        prevDot.addClass('active-dot');
    });
};


$(document).ready(main);
```

and here is the HTML that goes along with it:

```
<div class="slider">
    <div class="slide active-slide">
        <img src="pic1.jpg" alt="TBP">
    </div>

    <div class="slide">
        <img src="pic2.JPG" alt="TBP">
    </div>

    <div class="slide">
        <img src="pic3.jpg" alt="TBP">
    </div>

    <div class="slide">
        <img src="pic4.jpg" alt="TBP">
    </div>
</div>

<a href="#"><img class="left-arrow" src="left-arrow.svg" alt="go left!"></a>

    <ul class="slider-dots">
        <li class="dot active-dot">&bull;</li>
        <li class="dot">&bull;</li>
        <li class="dot">&bull;</li>
        <li class="dot">&bull;</li>
    </ul>

 <a href="#"><img class="right-arrow" src="right-arrow.svg" alt="bleh"></a>
```

Comment: Can you make a demo please? (on codepen or other)

Comment: `if(prevSlide.is(':first-child')){`, in this line I think you should have written, `if(currentSlide.is(':first-child')){`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think because you are missing $ in varriable `var currentSlide = ('.active-slide');`

Comment: You're a Godsend, thank you. I can't believe I missed that. Appreciate it. Sorry this wasn't a more interesting problem haha